# Дизассемблирование команды cmp eax, 0 (опкод 0x83)

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

В листинге дизассемблированного файла имею:

```
.text:00401296                 cmp     eax, 0
.text:00401299                 jz      short loc_4012B0
```

Пронзив исполняемый файл **hex-редактором**, лечу на адрес 696 (адрес первой команды cmp) и там смотрю такие байты:

```
83 F8 00
```

Пытаюсь разобраться..
Топаю на http://sparksandflames.com/files/x86InstructionChart.html
Там мне подсказывают, что

> 83 - SUB Ev Ib...

Вычитание? Не сравнение? В самой программе он работает как сравнение.. Привычный мир рушится...

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему 83 - вычитание, а не сравнение или опкод "модифицируется" каким-то спец. байтом?
2. Как вычислить опкод команды `mov eax,eax` (не `89 F8 00` случаем?).

- Как в этом случае будет влиять на ход программы байт `mod r/m`?
- Или `xor eax,eax`? (не `35 F8 F8` случаем?)

Видимо, просто запутался очень + не хватает знаний и нормально изложенного материала. Направьте, камрады.

Comment: Вот эта таблица: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x83 говорит, что опкоду 0x83 соответствуют операции ADD, OR, ADC, SBB, AND, SUB, XOR и CMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Команда целиком состоит из трех байт: `83 F8 00`

83h - это только часть опкода. Как уже заметил VladD, это может соответствовать командам ADD, OR, ADC, SBB, AND, SUB, XOR и CMP. Чтобы понять, что это за команда фактически, нужно смотреть следующий байт (F8h). Это байт MOD R/M, состоящих из 3 полей (по 2, 3, 3 бита):

```
F8 == 11 111 000
```

По второму полю этого байта можно определить конкретную команду (хотя, обычно оно отвечает за один из операндов) - как раз из списка ADD, OR, ADC, SBB, AND, SUB, XOR и CMP. Первое поле показывает, что второй (на самом деле первый) операнд - это регистр (или адрес в памяти, но в данном случае это все же регистр). `000` - это, собственно, код регистра, EAX.

Третий байт является вторым операндом команды - 0.

Больше по этой теме можно почитать, например, здесь: [Крис Касперски - Дизассемблирование в уме](http://www.e-reading.mobi/bookreader.php/133499/Kasperski_-_Dizassemblirovanie_v_ume.pdf).

А еще лучше - читать [руководства от Intel в оригинале](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Используемый вами справочник очень не полный.

> Как вычислить опкод команды `mov eax,eax`?

Скомпилировать и посмотреть, это наиболее надежный способ, или смотреть в руководстве от Intel.

> Или xor eax,eax? (не 35 F8 F8 случаем?)

Скорее `31 C0`. Второй байт - байт mod r/m, там просто указывается, что производится операция производится между регистром и регистром, и коды самих регистров:

```
11 000 000
```

(`000` в обоих случаях - обозначение регистра eax). А первый байт - не 35h, а 31h, т.к. операция не между регистром/памятью и значением, а между регистром и регистром/памятью.

Comment: Пожал бы Вам руку! Сколько прочел до этого и только сейчас въехал как работает mod r/m..
Из-за разных "постановок" битов "выбираются" и сами регистры и режимы...
А следует mor r/m  сразу за кодом операции)
Это ж.. гениально :D
Криса почитаю, обязателньо! Думаю тогда станет еще ясней!

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение содержимого регистра с числов равноценно вычитанию из регистра этого числа.

Т.е. по сути  `SUB eax 0` и `CMP eax 0` равноценны по результату. При совпаднеии числе в результате получается ноль и срабатывает переход `JZ`

В данном случае я думаю, что программист реализовавывл сравнение вычитанием, а `CMP` поставил слишком "умный" дизассемблер.

Comment: Небольшой комментарий:
1 - согласен, с поправкой на то, что при сравнении изменяются только флаги, но не операнды; 2 - в данном случае да, в общем случае - нет (`cmp`, в отличие от `sub`, не модифицирует операнды); 3 - нет, и программист написал `cmp`, и дизассемблер поставил `cmp`, инструкция из вопроса дизассемблируется вполне однозначно.